# how to extract row index from data.frame in R with quantmod package

Tags: r, quantmod

using the quantmod package, I am pulling stock data, as below

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('F')
head(F)
```

which gives the output

```
           F.Open F.High F.Low F.Close F.Volume
2007-01-03   7.56   7.67  7.44    7.51 78671500
2007-01-04   7.56   7.72  7.43    7.70 63545800
2007-01-05   7.72   7.75  7.57    7.62 40563800
2007-01-08   7.63   7.75  7.62    7.73 48941200
2007-01-09   7.75   7.86  7.73    7.79 56732500
2007-01-10   7.79   7.79  7.67    7.73 42398600
# and an unimportant(here) warning regarding download length
```

I want to be able to extract the obvious date column here, and work with the data as a data.frame, usually I would try to look up the column names and pull that column, but the dates are not included in a column!

Comment: sorry did not see that one. desired answer here with data.frame might be different enough?

Comment: Let others decide whether they considered it is a duplicate or not.

Comment: Duplicates often end up getting more hits than the originals because the way the problem is formulated is different. My understanding is they are not supposed to be deleted, unless they are obvious copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a data.frame, it is an xts. If you want to manipulate it as a data.frame  and get the dates (they come over as rownames) try:

```
   df <- data.frame(F)
   row.names(df)
```

Comment: works perfectly, I guess I have data.frames in my brain, don't use xts much. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
  dates <- index(F)
```

The quantmod package extracts the data in xts format. It might not always be advisable to convert an xts time series into a dataframe.

Comment: It is good to have the right way of using it here too.

Comment: No offense intended concerning your solution, which offers an answer that corresponds better to the description in the title of the OP. It's just that one loses many if not all functionalities provided by the quantmod package after such a format conversion.

Comment: In complete agreement.  But somethings do require data frames and one needs to be aware of both possibilities.